# Using ng-class to create a favourites icon

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-class to change an icon when it is clicked on but it also needs to change based on if it is in the local storage as well. So when a user clicks on the favourite icon it changes from an outline to solid.

This is where i am using the ng-class to change the icon, but i want it to change when it is clicked on through the ng-click.

```
<i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': liked, 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !liked}" ng-click="favicon(office.id); togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
```

This is the function that i have created to change the icon from outline to solid but it does not work. My previous function just returned $scope.liked=!$scope.liked, that one worked but it changed all of the icons instead of the individual icons.

```
var e = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
$scope.favicon = function(office){
if (e.indexOf(office) !== -1){
 return !$scope.liked;
}
else if (e.indexOf(office) == -1){
  return $scope.liked;
}
};
```

My second question is can i use this with ng-init to change the icons that have values in local storage when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value of `$scope.liked` merely returning it which will have no effect on your `ng-class`. You could change your if statement to something like.

That is why your old `ng-click` of `$scope.liked = !$scope.liked` worked because it was always toggling your variable on click.

```
var e = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
$scope.favicon = function(office){
    $scope.liked = e.indexOf(office) !== -1;
};
```